# How can I extract nouns from the response im using python and langchain

Tags: python, flask, langchain

I want to extract nouns from message: response and display it in console or just print them ,How to do that? I tired ntlk and textbob something like those but I don't know how to properly implement it.I even asked github copoilet but it is just displaying in random and not working.
I have a task that involves extracting nouns from a variable called message: response. I want to display the extracted nouns in the console or print them on the screen. How can I accomplish this task using Python? I have tried using some libraries like NLTK and TextBlob, but I am not sure how to use them correctly. I have also asked GitHub Copilot for help, but it did not generate any useful code. It just showed me some random output that did not work. Can anyone please help me with this problem?

```
from flask import Flask , render_template , jsonify ,request
from flask_cors import CORS
from textblob import TextBlob
import requests , openai , os
from langchain.llms import OpenAI
from langchain.chains import ConversationChain
from langchain.memory import ConversationSummaryBufferMemory
from datasets import load_dataset , Dataset
from langchain.text_splitter import RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter
import tiktoken
from getpass import getpass
from langchain.embeddings.openai import OpenAIEmbeddings
import pinecone
from tqdm.auto import tqdm
from uuid import uuid4
from langchain.vectorstores import Pinecone
from langchain.chat_models import ChatOpenAI
from langchain.chains import RetrievalQAWithSourcesChain
#flask 
llm=OpenAI()
memory=ConversationSummaryBufferMemory(llm=llm,max_token_limit=100)
app=Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)

#pinecone
trust_remote_code=True
data = load_dataset("wikipedia", "20220301.simple", split='train[:1000]')
data[6]
tokenizer = tiktoken.get_encoding('cl100k_base')

# create the length function
def tiktoken_len(text):
    tokens = tokenizer.encode(
        text,
        disallowed_special=()
    )
    return len(tokens)


tiktoken_len("hello I am a chunk of text and using the tiktoken_len function "
            "we can find the length of this chunk of text in tokens")

text_splitter = RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter(
    chunk_size=400,
    chunk_overlap=20,
    length_function=tiktoken_len,
    separators=["\n\n", "\n", " ", ""]
)

chunks = text_splitter.split_text(data[6]['text'])[:3]
tiktoken_len(chunks[0]), tiktoken_len(chunks[1]), tiktoken_len(chunks[2])
OPENAI_API_KEY = "API KEY"
model_name = 'text-embedding-ada-002'
embed = OpenAIEmbeddings(
    model=model_name,
    openai_api_key=OPENAI_API_KEY
)
texts = [
    'this is the first chunk of text',
    'then another second chunk of text is here'
]

res = embed.embed_documents(texts)
len(res), len(res[0])
# find API key in console at app.pinecone.io
YOUR_API_KEY = "API KEY"
# find ENV (cloud region) next to API key in console
YOUR_ENV = "gcp-starter"

index_name = 'langchain-retrieval-augmentation'
pinecone.init(
    api_key='API KEY',
    environment='gcp-starter'
)
index = pinecone.GRPCIndex(index_name)
batch_limit = 100
texts = []
metadatas = []
if len(texts) > 0:
    ids = [str(uuid4()) for _ in range(len(texts))]
    embeds = embed.embed_documents(texts)
    index.upsert(vectors=zip(ids, embeds, metadatas))
text_field = "text"

# switch back to normal index for langchain
index = pinecone.Index(index_name)

vectorstore = Pinecone(
    index, embed.embed_query, text_field
)
query="What is the capital of France?"
vectorstore.similarity_search(
    query,  # our search query
    k=3  # return 3 most relevant docs
)
# completion llm
llm = ChatOpenAI(
    openai_api_key='API KEY',
    model_name='gpt-3.5-turbo',
    temperature=0.0
)
qa_with_sources = RetrievalQAWithSourcesChain.from_chain_type(
    llm=llm,
    chain_type="stuff",
    retriever=vectorstore.as_retriever()
)
qa_with_sources(query)


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/data',methods=['POST'])
def getdata():
    data=request.get_json()
    text=data.get('data')
    user_input=text
    try:
        response=qa_with_sources(user_input)
        
        return jsonify({"message":response,"response":True})
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        error_message=f'Error:{str (e)}'
        return jsonify({"message":error_message,"response":False})
    

if __name__=='__main__':
    app.run(debug=True) 

 

#I want to extract the nouns from message: response and display it in console
```

Answer (score 1):

what you need for the extracting the nouns is POS (part of speech) tagging in NLTK.

below are the brief steps.

1. split the paragraph into sentences.
2. split the sentence into tokens
3. tag the tokens (results in list of tuples, where the first part of the tuple is the word, and second part of the tuple is the tag)

> ```
> tokenized = sent_tokenize(txt)
> for i in tokenized:
>     #Word tokenizers is used to find the words 
>     #and punctuation in a string
>     wordsList = nltk.word_tokenize(i)
>     #removing stop words from wordList 
>     wordsList = [w for w in wordsList if not w in stop_words] 
>  
>    #Using a Tagger. Which is part-of-speech 
>    #tagger or POS-tagger. 
>    tagged = nltk.pos_tag(wordsList)
> ```

sample output will be like

```
('Marriage', 'NN'), ('big', 'JJ'), ('step', 'NN'), ('one', 'CD'), ('’', 'NN'), ('life', 'NN')]
```

Any tuple(word) that has the second part that starts with NN is a noun. full reference here - https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/part-speech-tagging-stop-words-using-nltk-python/